# HTML-Putting the sliders next to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

There is a way to put the sliders  and the button next to the canvas? I've tried with `<div>` style but it moves the sliders on the top the page or on the bottom of the page. This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 512px;">
        <h1>Model of a Robot</h1>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
             Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
        </canvas>
    <button id= "switchProj">Change Projection type</button>
    <div>
        body angle -180 <input id="bodySlider" type="range"
        min="-180" max="180" step="10" value="0"
        />
        180
    </div>
    <div>
         head angle -45 <input id="headSlider" type="range"
         min="-45" max="45" step="5" value="0"
         />
         45
    </div>
    <div id="leftArmSlider">
        left arm angle -90 <input id="leftArmSlider" type="range"
        min="-90" max="-30" step="10" value="-30"
        />
        -30
    </div>
    <div id="rightArmSlider">
         right arm angle 30 <input id="rightArmSlider" type="range"
         min="30" max="90" step="10" value="30"
         />
         90
    </div>
    <div>
        left leg angle -30 <input id="leftLegSlider" type="range"
        min="-30" max="30" step="5" value="0"
        />
        30
    </div>
    <div>
        right leg angle -30 <input id="rightLegSlider" type="range"
        min="-30" max="30" step="5" value="0"
        />
        30
    </div>
    <div>
        zNear .01<input id="zNearSlider" type="range"
        min=".01" max="4" step="0.1" value="0.3" />
        4
    </div>
    <div>
        zFar 1<input id="zFarSlider" type="range"
        min="1" max="10" step="1.0" value="5" />
        10
    </div>
    <div>
        fov 10<input id="fovSlider" type="range"
        min="10" max="120" step="5" value="70" />
        120
    </div>
    <div>
        aspect 0.5<input id="aspectSlider" type="range"
        min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1" />
        2
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you thought about putting the elements in a row, then wrapping your sliders in the same div and defining them as a column next to a column of your robot's elements?

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Comment: Also @OP, the best practice would be to only post the code relevant to the problem you're facing, i.e. the divs of the sliders and the canvas

Answer (score 0):

Alright OP! First, I would suggest you use Bootstrap or something similar if you're not wanting to write much CSS yourself. Here's a suggestion to you using Bootstrap classes:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 512px;" class="col-sm-9">
        <h1>Model of a Robot</h1>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
                 Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        //sliders and stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This isn't perfect or anything, and I doubt it'll work for your project without tweaking it, but I think it's probably your path-of-least-resistance.

Comment: it moves the canvas and sliders on two different columns but it still moves the sliders on the bottom of the page even if it is supposed to put the two parts on the same row.

Comment: It's possible that this is happening because you're explicitly declaring the width of the div containing your canvas. Could you try removing the `style="margin: 0px auto; width: 512px;"` bit of your code and let me know what happens? It might not look ideal after you do this, but we can get it looking pretty once we get the overall layout of the page working.

Comment: it moves the canvas on the same column of the sliders

Comment: it moves the canvas on the left side of the page, to be clearer

Comment: So the elements are in-line now?

Comment: Yes! Canvas and sliders are in the same column!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot in this comment section?

Comment: I've added the screenshot in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the screenshot of the page!

Comment: So the answer I provided above is only going to work w/ Bootstrap installed, which it does not appear you have done! That's fine, it was a suggestion. From here, I'd recommend giving this a read: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

Comment: Using that, you should be able to define columns for your code to sit on. You should try using those to format your page by having a column containing your sliders sitting next to a column containing your canvas. Keep in mind that you may still have your sliders wrap to the bottom of the page if your canvas has an explicit width that doesn't give your sliders enough room!

Comment: It should work with Microsoft Edge 10.0 and I got it but it still doesn't work!